# How do I update a child db table when populating database in ruby on ralls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have the following tables in my database:

- User(s) - has one profile, has many PhotoAlbums
- Profile(s) - belongs to user
- PhotoAlbum(s) - belongs to user, has many photos
- Photo(s) - belongs to PhotoAlbum

Faker works fine when it comes to populating my users table but I now wish to update my profiles table also but it doesn't work at all. The rows in the db still remain empty. I have no errors showing up when I run rake db:populate.

Am I missing something, please help me see where I'm going wrong and help me come up with a solution as this will help me when I need to populate my other tables too. What I learn from this answer can help me with other tasks I have coming up.

libs/task/sample_data.rake

```
   namespace :db do
        desc "Create user records in the development database."
        task :populate => :environment do
          require 'faker'


          def randomDate(params={})
            years_back = params[:year_range] || 5
            latest_year  = params [:year_latest] || 0
            year = (rand * (years_back)).ceil + (Time.now.year - latest_year - years_back)
            month = (rand * 12).ceil
            day = (rand * 31).ceil
            series = [date = Time.local(year, month, day)]
            if params[:series]
              params[:series].each do |some_time_after|
                series << series.last + (rand * some_time_after).ceil
              end
              return series
            end
            date
          end

          def decimal_selection_array(start,limit,step_size=1)
            decimal_array = (start..limit).step(step_size).map{|i| i.to_s}.to_a
            decimal_array.insert(0,"Below #{start.to_f}")
            decimal_array.insert(-1,"Above #{limit.to_f}")
          end

          100.times do |n|
            username = "#{Faker::Name.first_name}#{n}"
            u = User.create!(
              :username => username,
              :email => Faker::Internet.email,
              :password => "foobar"
            )


            u.profile.update_attributes(
          :motd                => Faker::Lorem.words,

          #Profile details
          :first_name          => Faker::Name.first_name,
          :last_name           => Faker::Name.last_name,
          :birthday            => randomDate(:year_range => 60, :year_latest => 22),     
          :gender              => (1..2).to_a.sample,
          :marital_status      => (1..7).to_a.sample,
          :sexual_preference   => (1..3).to_a.sample,
          :ethnicity           => (1..10).to_a.sample,
          :country             => Faker::Address.country,
          :location            => Faker::Address.country,

          #About the user
          :about_me            => Faker::Lorem.paragraph,

          #Personal stats
          :height              => decimal_selection_array(5.0,7.0,0.1).to_a.sample,
          :body_type           => (1..7).to_a.sample,
          :eye_colour          => (1..6).to_a.sample,
          :drugs               => (1..4).to_a.sample,
          :alcohol             => (1..4).to_a.sample,
          :cigarettes          => (1..3).to_a.sample,
          :likes               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :dislikes            => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :bad_habits          => Faker::Lorem.sentence,

          #Favourite things
          :food                => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :music               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :television          => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :book                => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :animal              => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :place               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
          :possesion           => Faker::Lorem.sentence


            )





        end
      end
    end
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

commenting out:

```
before_safe :build_profile
```

in my User model

and my editing my rake task to look like this:

```
# before running this task comment out: before_create :build_profile in user.rb in order to make this work correctly

namespace :db do
    desc "Create user records in the development database."
    task :populate => :environment do
      require 'faker'


      def randomDate
        "#{(1900..2012).to_a.sample}-#{(1..12).to_a.sample}-#{(1..28).to_a.sample}"
      end

      def decimal_selection_array(start,limit,step_size=1)
        decimal_array = (start..limit).step(step_size).map{|i| i.to_s}.to_a
        decimal_array.insert(0,"Below #{start.to_f}")
        decimal_array.insert(-1,"Above #{limit.to_f}")
      end

      1000.times do |n|
        username = "#{Faker::Name.first_name}#{n+1}"
        User.create!(
          :username => username.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, ''),
          :email => Faker::Internet.email,
          :password => "foobar"
        )

        Profile.create!(
      :user_id             => "#{n+1}",
      :motd                => Faker::Lorem.sentence,

      #Profile details
      :first_name          => Faker::Name.first_name.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, ''),
      :last_name           => Faker::Name.last_name.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, ''),
      :birthday            => randomDate,     
      :gender              => (1..2).to_a.sample,
      :marital_status      => (1..7).to_a.sample,
      :sexual_preference   => (1..3).to_a.sample,
      :ethnicity           => (1..10).to_a.sample,
      :country             => Faker::Address.country,
      :location            => Faker::Address.country,

      #About the user
      :about_me            => Faker::Lorem.paragraph,

      #Personal stats
      :height              => decimal_selection_array(5.0,7.0,0.1).to_a.sample,
      :body_type           => (1..7).to_a.sample,
      :hair                => (1..7).to_a.sample,
      :eye_colour          => (1..6).to_a.sample,
      :drugs               => (1..4).to_a.sample,
      :alcohol             => (1..4).to_a.sample,
      :cigarettes          => (1..3).to_a.sample,
      :likes               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :dislikes            => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :bad_habits          => Faker::Lorem.sentence,

      #Favourite things
      :food                => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :sport               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :music               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :television          => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :book                => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :animal              => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :place               => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
      :possession          => Faker::Lorem.sentence


        )


    end
  end
end
```

I had to make a few adjustments to what Faker was passing into my db as things were failing validation. Things like usernames with characters other than letters and numbers and this also happened with last_name too. So I had to filter all that stuff out and then I ran the take task and successfully updated my database with 1000 users with profile information.

All I have to do is uncomment the before_create any time I want to add sample data to stop profile rows being created for users on create.

I also added user_id to attr_accessible in my Profile model so that the user_id column could be populated with numbers 1 to 1000 which would match them up with a user.

Answer (score 0):

User profile (`u.profile`) does not exist when calling `u.profile.update_attributes(params)`.
You should call `u.create_profile(params)` instead.

Using [nested attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods) could also help.

Comment: This would create a profile row for a user twice as 1 in created automatically on user signup.

Comment: Ok, so users ar not only automatically generated but can also sign up?
Or is the profile created via a hook e.g. `after_create :create_profile`?
 
Please explain.

Comment: before_create :build_profile is my User.rb file for my users table. When a user signs_up the row for their profile is automatically created too. Storing their id from the users table in the user_id column of the profiles table.

Comment: This was not evident from the question. Have you tried creating a single user/profile by hand (via console)?

Comment: and updating of profiles with faker generated data? Could be that that data is not valid?

Comment: I'm using the bang method so if any validation fails it'll tell me and I turned off validation for the ones that were failing. Using  u.create_profile! works but 2 rows are create. 1 during user creation which remains empty and the second one during create_profile and this one shows data. I don't want this though. I'd just like the row created on signup updated.